# Можете помочь? не работает калькулятор

Tags: java, android

Все id дал правильно не думаю, что проблема в этом...
чтобы не нажал, делает только сложение (+, -, *, /  - но делает только сложение).. не знаю в чем проблема, потому что я и сам новичок, еще 4 дня как изучаю андроид....спасибо))

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Float mValueone, mValuetwo;
boolean madd, msub, mmult, mdiv;

private EditText editText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button buttonc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button29);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv5);
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv6);
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv7);
    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv8);
    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv9);
    Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiv0);
    Button buttonadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gumarum);
    Button buttonsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hanum);
    Button buttonmult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bazm);
    Button buttondiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bajanum);
    Button buttonequals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.havasar);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setText(editText.getText()+"1");
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        editText.setText(editText.getText()+"2");
    }
});

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        editText.setText(editText.getText()+"3");
    }
});

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"4");
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"5");
        }
    });

    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"6");
        }
    });

    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"7");
        }
    });


    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"8");
        }
    });


    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"9");
        }
    });


    button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"0");
        }
    });

    buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if(editText==null){
               editText.setText("");
           }else {
            mValueone = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");
               madd = true;
               editText.setText(null);
           }
        }
    });

    buttonsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(editText==null){
                editText.setText("");
            }else {
                mValueone = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");
                msub = true;
                editText.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });

    buttonmult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(editText==null){
                editText.setText("");
            }else {
                mValueone = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");
                mmult = true;
                editText.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });

    buttondiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(editText==null){
                editText.setText("");
            }else {
                mValueone = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");
                mdiv = true;
                editText.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });

    buttonequals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mValuetwo = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");

            if(madd=true){
                editText.setText((mValueone+mValuetwo+""));
                madd=false;
            }

            if(msub=true){
                editText.setText((mValueone-mValuetwo+""));
                msub=false;
            }


            if(mmult=true){
               editText.setText((mValueone*mValuetwo+""));
                mmult=false;
            }

            if (mdiv=true){
                editText.setText((mValueone/mValuetwo+""));
                mdiv=false;
            }
        }
    });

    buttonc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mValuetwo = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText()+"");

    if(madd=true){
        editText.setText((mValueone+mValuetwo+""));
        madd=false;
    }

    if(msub=true){
        editText.setText((mValueone-mValuetwo+""));
        msub=false;
    }


    if(mmult=true){
       editText.setText((mValueone*mValuetwo+""));
        mmult=false;
    }

    if (mdiv=true){
        editText.setText((mValueone/mValuetwo+""));
        mdiv=false;
    }
}
```

`madd=true` - это не сравнение, это присваивание. Сравнение - `madd == true`.
В трех других `if` аналогично.

Comment: Спс вам большое)) помог